# How might this code be adjusted for the background of a box?

Tags: css

A StackOverflow user named "sopanha" said that this could be used to get a background to change on a page.  How could it be adjusted to apply the the background of a box?

Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var header = $('body');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(http://placekitten.com/100)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/200)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/300)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/400)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to replace this line with your box:

```
var header = $('body');
```

body refers to the  Tag in HTML. You can replace it by either all your boxes (read: < div>) or by the specific box id with a preceding hashtag.

```
var header = $('#id_of_my_box');
```

Corresponding HTML-Code

```
<div id="id_of_my_box">My background changes</div>
```

Comment: What would I call the 'background' in the CSS code of "id_of_my_box"?